# Android Rss Webview Error

Tags: android, webview, rss, reader

I am trying to pass the link to webview in my RSS reader, but once I click on the headline, I get this error in my webview; where I pass the link.

Error Message:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p8knqtzkitftst/AiLgtKw6hmtwz_O-M6Q8yCGeHkraYzGF3Qnoa8RYSCvG.jpg?dl=0

Comment: What error ? What is that mean this error?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please check here https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p8knqtzkitftst/AiLgtKw6hmtwz_O-M6Q8yCGeHkraYzGF3Qnoa8RYSCvG.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Post your xml format (I guess it is in xml) and code you are using to parse it, as well as your full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks I just solved the problem. The Problem was while fecthing the url from website. it was adding extra string value to the final url and i replaced by string.replace("wrong url", "Correct url");

Comment: Hi there. Images at Dropbox are not suitable for Stack Overflow questions, since the links often break, as has happened here. Please add questions to imgur.com or, better still, use the image upload feature. (Voting to close question).